# Access char[] variable from C language's structure to go

Tags: c, go

Here I have test.h header file and in this header file I have declared one char a[10] variable. I have created one test.c file which includes test.h and assigns "Test" as a value. Now I have main.go file which will use that variable. Below are my code details.

test.h: this my header file

```
#ifndef _TEST_H
#define _TEST_H

typedef struct student student;
struct student {
    
          char a[10];
};
student* show();

#endif
```

test.c: C source file which access test.h file and assign that variable `a[10]` with "Test"

```
#include "test.h"
#include <string.h>

student* show()
{
struct student *s= malloc(sizeof(struct student) * 1);
strcpy(s[0].a,"Test");
return s;
}
```

main.go

```
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include "test.h"
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
         "unsafe"
    )

func main() {
s:= C.show();
defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(s))
sSlice := (*[1]C.struct_student)(unsafe.Pointer(s));
fmt.Println(sSlice);
for _, ss := range sSlice {

  fmt.Printf("A...%s", ss.a)   //Here I want to access that variable
}
}
```

But Instead of showing Test its showing `&[{[84 101 115 116 0 0 0 0 0 0]}]`.

Comment: 84 101 115 116 are the ASCII character values for "Test". There's no distinction between an array of characters and a string in C, so Go isn't assuming anything for you.

Comment: Ok. Now I am trying to convert that ASCII value and get real value by using fmt.Printf("A...%s", string(ss.a)) but it's giving cannot convert ss.a (type [10]_Ctype_char) to type string error

Comment: You'll have to convert the C string to a Go string to get *convenient* use of it. But be very careful when dealing with a fixed-size C array: it might contain something other than a C string! If so, treating it *as if* it held a C string could do bad thing (run off the end of the array, perhaps into unreadable memory => runtime failure).

Comment: To convert I am using fmt.Printf("A...%s",C.GoString(ss.a)) but getting cannot use ss.a (type [10]_Ctype_char) as type *_Ctype_char in argument to _Cfunc_GoString error

Comment: Please [`go fmt`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Gofmt__reformat__package_sources) your Go source code before posting. It is very difficult to read with irregular indentation. ([`clang-format`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) would help make the C code more legible too.)

Comment: Ok. Next time I will follow all the format.

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` format specifier for Go works with Go strings and Go slices and arrays whose element type has the [underlying type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) `byte` (such as `[]byte`).

The `ss.a` field, as converted by `cgo`, has the Go type `[10]C.char`.

On many platforms, [`C.char` is a *signed* character type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Character_types), while Go's `byte` is always *unsigned*. So it may be the case that `C.char` has the underlying Go type `int8` instead of `byte` (`uint8`), in which case `fmt` cannot print it using `%s`. In order to print it, you need to change the type.

---

One simple way to do that is to make a copy using `C.GoString`. `C.GoString` expects a `*C.char`, which in this case is the address of `ss.a[0]`:

```golang
    for _, ss := range sSlice {
        s := C.GoString(&ss.a[0])
        fmt.Printf("A...%s\n", s)
    }
```

(In C, `ss.a` and `&ss.a[0]` are equivalent, because C more-or-less does not distinguish between arrays and pointers. However, in Go arrays and pointers are completely distinct types.)

---

If the string may be large, you might want to avoid copying the entire slice into the Go heap.

You can express the change of type using `unsafe.Pointer` and convert it to a slice using Go 1.17's [`unsafe.Slice`](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Slice):

```golang
    for _, ss := range sSlice {
        s := unsafe.Slice((*byte)((unsafe.Pointer)(&ss.a[0])), len(ss.a))
        fmt.Printf("A...%s\n", s)
    }
```

Or, you could use the [`ConvertAt`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bcmills/unsafeslice#ConvertAt) function from my `unsafeslice` package to express it a bit more simply:

```golang
    for _, ss := range sSlice {
        var s []byte
        unsafeslice.ConvertAt(&s, ss.a[:])
        fmt.Printf("A...%s\n", s)
    }
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I am using last approach which is simple.